# Using jqueryui dialog as a substitute for javascript core confirm()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, confirm

I want to make a substitute for javascript core confirm() in jquery ui dialog.I use this code
bellow.But it returns some error.

```
function CreateDialog(){
$("#diag-conf").dialog({show:'drop',hide:'drop',autoOpen:false,resizable:false,draggable:true,height:150,width:410,title:'Facebook Session Error!',modal:true,buttons:{"CONTINUE":function(){$(this).dialog("close");top.location.href=re_auth;},"CANCEL":function(){$(this).dialog("close");}}});
}
function digOpn(){
    var m='my msg';
    $('#digmsg').html(m);
    //$("#diag-conf").dialog("open");
    CreateDialog();
}
function sess_chk(){
   if(fb_ses())return true; 
   else 
   {
       digOpn();
       return false;
    } 
}
```

Now when i call sess_chk() function from my code in an onclick event it doesn't fire ui dialog rather throw an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'propAttr' (jquery-ui.min.js:258)
```

What am i doing wrong here.??!!

**EDIT:**

> After some debugging i have seen that 'propAttr' error was popping
>   because of multiple instance of jquery ui.So anyway my code is working
>   perfect now.Even though i've seen that  in {digOpn();return false}
>   "return false" doesn't wait for my ui dialog click value and executes
>   immediately.But that doesn't cause me any trouble though.Thanks for
>   your kind appreciations.

Comment: What versions of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: jQuery UI 1.8.16 and jQuery v1.6.2

Comment: i just want to show a confirmation dialog in digOpn().So you can change my code to working one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error must be elsewhere on your page (you don't even have `propAttr` in the code you posted).

The following piece of code works perfectly for me:

```
function CreateDialog() {
    $("#diag-conf").dialog({
        show:'drop',
        hide:'drop',
        autoOpen:false,
        resizable:false,
        draggable:true,
        height:150,
        width:410,
        title:'Facebook Session Error!',
        modal:true,
        buttons:{
            "CONTINUE":function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
                top.location.href=re_auth;
            },
            "CANCEL":function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
function digOpn(){
    var m ='my msg';
    $('#digmsg').html(m);
    CreateDialog();
    $("#diag-conf").dialog("open");
}

digOpn();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TBbAm/

Comment: I have updated my code. `else 
   {
       digOpn();
       return false;
    }` now return false is called before i can confirm.

Comment: @neo-nant: You have not shown in your code what `fb_ses()` does. Your error is definitely there...